# javascript error in onclick function

Tags: javascript

I have an error when I call an onclick function.
My HTML is just a table that I fill with Javascript  :

```
for(var i=0;i<8;i++){
    txt+='<tr id="ligne'+ligne+'">';
    for(var j=1;j<9;j++){

        id=ligne+'c'+j;
        txt+='<td id="'+id+'" class="'+class_col+'" >';

        txt+= '</td>';

    }
    txt+='</tr>';

    ligne++;
}
document.getElementById("echiquier").innerHTML = txt;
```

This works fine, but when I make a function to change the background of a td when clicked, I have the error "undefined is not a function". My function is :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td").addEventListener('click', function(){
    id = this.id;
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = "blue";
});
```

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns a html collection of elements matching that tag name, you need to access each element and set the listener, ie `getElementsByTagName("td")[0].addEventListener`

Comment: You could have tried to debug parts of your code first: e. g. what does `getElementsByTagName("td")` return? An `HTMLElement` or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td").addEventListener
```

This will not work because `document.getElementsByTagName("td")` returns an `HTMLCollection` instead of an `HTMLElement`. You need to index the desired element.

For example

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0]
```

will return the first `td` element. If you work in a loop you can use

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].addEventListener
```

In the inner part of the function you can use `this` directly. No need to retrieve the `id` and search for it again (the ID may not even exist). Just use

```
this.style.background = "blue";
```

---

You can also give event delegation a try:

```
document.getElementById("yourTableElement")
  .addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName=='TD'){
      e.target.style.background = "blue";
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting the error is because `addEventListener()` does not work on multiple event targets (i.e. elements).

Try the below solution:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('td'), function (element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    });
});
```

Personally, I think using `Array.prototype.forEach.call()` is cleaner than going through a `for` loop and dealing with indices. Using the method above, we are saying that we should treat `HTMLCollection` like an `Array`. This way, we can use Array methods on DOM collections.